# how to make href link in rails text_area into real href link?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

i simply wrote input field in create view : 
f.text_area :content ...
and in show view :

so, when i type "www.google.com" in the input text_area and submit; as a result, the content shows view simply give a text div, not a link.
when i type "www.g.com", it works, as the content shows a real link, which was converted by html_safe method.

while, how can i make sure, any of those user input, which looks like link, can be automatically convert into an href?

by js? or rails?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [autolink](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link). This used to be in Rails core but since 3.1 has been extracted to a gem.
https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink